# Creating a MapReduce query in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have a slight problem. Until now, I’m not so deep in the Mongo DB stuff. More like the SQL guy, but now I have to crate a Map Reduce query.

My data looks like this:

[image]

Every student has multiple lectures. Now I want a list of all lectures (no duplicates) and the number of students visiting it.

```
function() {
emit(this.vorlesungen, this._id);
};


function(VL, students) {
                      return Array.sum(students);
                  };
```

This gives me some strange result I can´t figure out.

Some hints would be great.

Comment: Please update your question with what the strange output is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the data that you're expecting but give it a try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$unwind : "$vorlesungen"},
   {$group : {_id : "$vorlesungen", studentCount: {$sum : 1}}}
])
```

Comment: Not realy, but thanks for your help. I just keep trying

Comment: if you've not found an answer yet, maybe you can post your expected data and see if others can help you with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a aulution by myself:

Map:

```js
function() {
this.vorlesungen.forEach(function (elem) {
for(vlname in elem) {
emit(vlname, 1);
}
});
```

Reduce:

```js
function(key, values) {
return Array.sum(values);
}
```